# Proving that the functional $T_x : (C[0,1], \| \cdot \|_1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, where $T_x(f) = f(x)$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

So, I need to show that the functional $T_x : (C[0,1], \| \cdot  \|_1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded. That means that I need to show that there is no $M>0$ such that $|T_x(f)| \leq M \|f\|_1 $. Equivalently, I need to prove that there is no $M>0$ such that $ |f(x)| \leq M \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt $. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or equivalently, find a sequence $(f_{n})\subseteq C[0,1]$ such that $\|f\|_{L^{1}}=1$ and $T_{x}(f_{n})\rightarrow\infty$.

Without loss of generality, set $x=0$.

Consider $f_{n}(t)=-n^{2}t+n$ for $t\in[0,1/n]$ and $f_{n}(t)=0$ for $t\in[1/n,1]$, then $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}}=1$ and $T_{0}(f_{n})=n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Could you please tell me why that is equivalent?

Comment: We have $|T_{x}(f/\|f\|)|\leq M$, now let $g=f/\|f\|$ so $\|g\|=1$. To show that such an $M$ does not exist, so just try to show that $T_{x}(g)$ tends to infinity as $g$ is running.

Comment: how is $\|f_n\|_1=1$?

Comment: It is just a matter of integration, or you can see from the graph about its area.

Comment: @J.Spil, I made a typo, the triangle is what I meant. Just changed, have a look, thanks.